# simple search engine

Tags: delphi, full-text-search

I am trying to write program its like a simple search engine, in this program the user is supposed to enter a search keyword into an edit box and then he can click the search button, and the program is supposed to open a specific text file from the directory and find a matching word to that keyword in this text file. I am using Delphi 2007. thank you

Comment: wow... clarifications maybe? what are they looking for? what is being returned? what are the contents of the "text file?"

Comment: what have you done so far? Where are you struggling? Can you design the form? Can you open the file? Are you getting false positives?

Comment: We need more information please. The question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to find a string in another string. Take a look at this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a unix system, send a call to [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). If you are on a windows system, install [grep for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the source code for the open source project [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org).  It contains a text search engine (grep) that works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I have written something similar in C# - [Searcharoo.net](http://www.searcharoo.net/) - you can download the source code from there.

What might be more useful, though, are the articles that I wrote describing how it works... This description of how [Version 1](http://www.searcharoo.net/SearcharooV1/) might be of some use - although I'm probably biased since I wrote it (back in 2004).

Your question is pretty open so I'm not sure if this will help - particularly since I don't know Delphi and how different it is to C# - but hope it helps...